# Counting within multiple for loops in a Jijna2 Template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I am trying to count by using a variable that needs to persist its value between multiple loops. My variables seem to be getting lost (reset to 0) in between every loop. Here is the code I am using:

```
{% for state in csvrows|groupby('state') %}
      <tr class="staterow"><td valign="baseline" class="state" colspan="6">{{ state.grouper }}</td><tr>
    {% for city in state.list|groupby('city') %}
        {% for row in city.list %}
        <tr><td class="spacer"></td>
                <td class="city">{% if loop.first %}{{ row.city }}{% endif %}</td>
                <td class="app">{{ row.application_name }}</td>
                <td class="risk">{{ row.risk }}</td>
                <td class="title">{{ row.title }}</td>
                <td class="remediation">{{ row.expected_remediation_date }}</td>

            {% if row.risk|lower == "critical" %}
            {% set crit = crit  + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.risk|lower == "high" %}
            {% set high = high + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.risk == "Medium" %}
            {% set med = med + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.risk|lower == "low" %}
            {% set low = low + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
            {% if row.risk|lower == "informational" %}
            {% set info = info + 1 %}
            {% endif %}

                <td>C: {{ crit }} H:{{ high }} M:{{ med }} L:{{ low }} I:{{ info }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Every time the `state.list|groupby('city')` loop begins again I lose my values for `crit, high, med, low and info`.

How can I append to these values and have the values persist between the iterations of the `state.list|groupby('city')` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can define `crit`, `high`, `med`, `low` and `info` before loop
`{% for city in state.list|groupby('city') %}`

Like

```
{% for state in csvrows|groupby('state') %}
     <tr class="staterow"><td valign="baseline" class="state" colspan="6">{{ state.grouper }}</td><tr>
    {% set crit = 0 %}
    {% set high = 0 %}
    {% set med = 0 %}
    {% set low = 0 %}
    {% set info = 0 %}
    {% for city in state.list|groupby('city') %}
        {% for row in city.list %}
        <tr><td class="spacer"></td>
        ...
        ...
        ...
        {% if row.risk|lower == "critical" %}
        {% set crit = crit  + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.risk|lower == "high" %}
        {% set high = high + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.risk == "Medium" %}
        {% set med = med + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.risk|lower == "low" %}
        {% set low = low + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.risk|lower == "informational" %}
        {% set info = info + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        ...
        ...
```

Hope this can be help you.

My Example code is here

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    render = """
    {% set val = 0 %}
    {% for i in [0, 1, 2, 3] %}
    {% set val = val + 2 %}
    <h3>{{ val }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
    """
    return render_template_string(render)
```

The above will render

> > #### 2
> >
> > #### 4
> >
> > #### 6
> >
> > #### 8

Comment: Thanks for this. I am already declaring my variables, but the issues is that I need to count between a loop within a loop. In your example there would be a second loop where you are setting your new value.

Comment: Right before the first line of the example. `{% for state in csvrows|groupby('state') %}`